# Let $U \subset \mathbb{R}^{m}$ be a open subset. Does there exists $f \in C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R}^{m})$ such that $U=f^{-1}\{(0,\infty)\}$?

Tags: real-analysis, smooth-functions

Let $U \subset \mathbb{R}^{m}$ be a open subset. Does there exists $f \in C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R}^{m})$ such that $U=f^{-1}\{(0,\infty)\}$?

Let $F=\mathbb{R}^{m}\setminus U$. I tried to use the results related to the partition of unity to construct (explicitly) a smooth function such that $f^{-1}(\{0\})=F$.

However, through this construction I can't guarantee that this function has compact support.

Comment: In my construction, $f(x)=\prod_{i=1}^{\infty} f_i(x)$, where $f_i^{-1}(0)=K_i=\{x \in F: i \leq |x| \leq i+1\}$ and $f_i(\mathbb{R}^{m}\setminus U_i)=1$ where $U_i=\{x \in \mathbb{R}^{m}:i-1<|x|<i+2\}$. Therefore, $f^{-1}(0)=\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}f_i^{-1}(0)=\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty} K_i=F$. Can you see how this will imply that $f$ has compact support?

Comment: Suppose that $U$ bounded. Since $U \subset \overline{U}$ then $\mathbb{R}^{m} \setminus \overline{U} \subset \mathbb{R}^{m} \setminus U=F$. Therefore, if $x \in \mathbb{R}^{m} \setminus \overline{U}$ then $f(x)=0$, that is, $f(x)=0$ outside of the compact $\overline{U}$. Is that the reasoning?

Comment: Based in your comments, I think that the correct statement is: Let $U\subset \mathbb{R}^{m}$ be a open subset. Then, there exists $f:\mathbb{R}^{m} \rightarrow [0,\infty)$, $f \in C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R}^{m})$ such that $f^{-1}(0,\infty)=U$ if, and only if, $U$ is bounded.